# How can I showcase the navigation drawer?

Tags: android

I'm using this library: https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView

How can I showcase the 3 bar button, clicking which the navigation drawer opens, in the top left corner of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu button (**3 Bar button**) can be accessed from toolbar

Try this :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (toolbar != null && toolbar.getChildCount() > 1) {
        final View view = toolbar.getChildAt(1);
        new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(view)
                .setDismissText("GOT IT")
                .setContentText("This is some amazing feature you should know about")
                .setDelay(1000) // optional but starting animations immediately in onCreate can make them choppy
                .singleUse("100") // provide a unique ID used to ensure it is only shown once
                .show();
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```